# Could you guide me to setup Live Http Steaming server with DashCast?

Tags: streaming

Personally I really dont like to ask such questions, but unfortunately this is where I am completely ignorant. I suppose to construct a live streaming server with DashCast over Apache Server. Presently, I setup DashCast but I do not know how to serve it through a web server Server. I guess after I deal with the server, I need to get it video by a Dash capable Javascript Client from the browser.

Would you suggest me any reference, pathway or anything for this problem? Any help is appreciated.